# What is the name of the maximum source to drain differential for a FET?

Tags: mosfet, differential, fet

I'm working with high voltage,  high power motor applications,  and it's slipping me right now; what is the name for the maximum voltage between the drain and source of a FET?

Edit: sorry for the confusion,  guys.  I typed this up on mobile,  and i mixed the names up from somewhere.

Comment: Vgsmax? Maximum gate-source voltage?

Comment: @winny i thought that there was a two word name for it.  The ______ voltage

Comment: Are you thinking about Miller?

Comment: Title says drain, text says source ... answers may or may not make sense.

Comment: VTC for being completely unclear about what you're asking, you even edited the title from one wrong entry to another equally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're many kinds of FET. They are similar, but they also have differences. I assume you are talking about MOSFET, because it is the most common one.

MOSFET has three terminals, Drain, Source and Gate. You can simply treat MOSFET as a switch( like pic below), gate is the terminal decide if the switch is open or close. So there is a voltage which is called threshold Voltage. 
[image]

The gate to source voltage (Vgs) must either be smaller or bigger than this voltage( this is depend on the type of MOSFET.) in order to work properly. But there is no typical name for the maximum gate voltage. You can simply call it Vgmax, i think it is decide by the manufacturer of the MOSFET, and will be showed on the data sheet.

As I said previously, voltage on the gate is just the voltage for open or closing the MOSFET, it doesn't need to reach its maximum.

And if it is used to control some high voltage devices, I will be more concerned about the drain to source voltage and current go through it, it will probably exceed the MOSFET's limit. By my own experience, I will recommend other device like Solid state Relay.

PS: From my knowledge, there is also no certain name to call source to drain differential. You can just call it Vdsmax.it does exist, i think you can also find it on the data sheet. Over this limit will damage the device.

And aslo like the Vgate, it has a certain voltage level, that after this level, the MOSFET will fully work.

Comment: Oh! So they measure drain to source voltage wrather than source to drain.

Comment: I must have misguided my question somewhere

Comment: @tuskiomi edit my answer, it pretty much work the same way as Vgate.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a useful concept, so there is no term for it. It would be Vds(max) - Vgs(min).

Comment: What if i need a fet to control a 10kv supply? Wouldn't it be useful to know if my fet would break down or hold up?

Comment: Since max/min gate/source voltages are typically about 20 volts, no.

Comment: Then how do we have switching power supplies that work for over 20 volts? Eg: 42V ESCs for brushless motors?

Comment: It's simple - source is grounded (or near enough) and gate drive is referenced to ground. Drain goes to load, which is connected to V+. That's for n-channel of course. P-channel is used much the same, but source goes to V+, and the gate often requires level-shifting to keep it within 20 volts of V+.